# retrofit 2 : execute().body() method stops and throw me back nothing (no error and of course not my data)

Tags: android, retrofit2

I meet a problem recovering the data on my database using a retrofit2 function call.execute().body(). My app stops when it arrives at that point. i don't know why there is no error message : it just stops. i have also tryed with call.enqueu etc ... to see what's going on in the 'onFailure' overrided method. but it doesn't enter in it.
maybe a parsing problem ? maybe something else ? 
i have seriously no clue.
And I have other pieces of code that works exactly the same. so ... 
thank you.
Here is my method :

```
 public CalendrierDisponibilite CallBy(int idPersonne) throws IOException {
            Call<CalendrierDisponibilite> call = userService.getCalendrierDisponibilite(idPersonne);
            Log.d("CallBy: " , call.execute().errorBody().toString());
             calendrier = call.execute().body();
  return calendrier;
    }
```

here is my Api Interface :

```
 @GET("calendrierdisponibilites/{id}")
    Call<CalendrierDisponibilite> getCalendrierDisponibilite(@Query("id") int id);
```

here is my model :

```
package com.example.dupla.sparktennis.entities;

import android.databinding.BaseObservable;
import android.databinding.Bindable;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

/**
 * Created by Remi on 2017-10-12.
 */

public class CalendrierDisponibilite extends BaseObservable implements Parcelable{


    @SerializedName("idcalendrier")
    @Expose
    private int idcalendrier;


    @SerializedName("iduser")
    @Expose
    private int iduser;


    @SerializedName("lundimatin")
    @Expose
    private int lundimatin;


    @SerializedName("lundiapmidi")
    @Expose
    private int lundiapmidi;


    @SerializedName("lundisoir")
    @Expose
    private int lundisoir;


    @SerializedName("mardimatin")
    @Expose
    private int mardimatin;


    @SerializedName("mardiapmidi")
    @Expose
    private int mardiapmidi;


    @SerializedName("mardisoir")
    @Expose
    private int mardisoir;


    @SerializedName("mercredimatin")
    @Expose
    private int mercredimatin;


    @SerializedName("mercrediapmidi")
    @Expose
    private int mercrediapmidi;


    @SerializedName("mercredisoir")
    @Expose
    private int mercredisoir;


    @SerializedName("jeudimatin")
    @Expose
    private int jeudimatin;


    @SerializedName("jeudiapmidi")
    @Expose
    private int jeudiapmidi;


    @SerializedName("jeudisoir")
    @Expose
    private int jeudisoir;


    @SerializedName("vendredimatin")
    @Expose
    private int vendredimatin;


    @SerializedName("vendrediapmidi")
    @Expose
    private int vendrediapmidi;


    @SerializedName("vendredisoir")
    @Expose
    private int vendredisoir;


    @SerializedName("weekendmatin")
    @Expose
    private int weekendmatin;


    @SerializedName("weekendapmidi")
    @Expose
    private int weekendapmidi;


    @SerializedName("weekendsoir")
    @Expose
    private int weekendsoir;


    @SerializedName("DateModification")
    @Expose
    private int dateModification;
/*
    @SerializedName("tstBool")
    @Expose
    private int tstBool;
*/
    public CalendrierDisponibilite(int idcalendrier, int iduser, int lundimatin, int lundiapmidi, int lundisoir, int mardimatin, int mardiapmidi, int mardisoir, int mercredimatin, int mercrediapmidi, int mercredisoir, int jeudimatin, int jeudiapmidi, int jeudisoir, int vendredimatin, int vendrediapmidi, int vendredisoir, int weekendmatin, int weekendapmidi, int weekendsoir , int test) {
        this.idcalendrier = idcalendrier;
        this.iduser = iduser;
        this.lundimatin = lundimatin;
        this.lundiapmidi = lundiapmidi;
        this.lundisoir = lundisoir;
        this.mardimatin = mardimatin;
        this.mardiapmidi = mardiapmidi;
        this.mardisoir = mardisoir;
        this.mercredimatin = mercredimatin;
        this.mercrediapmidi = mercrediapmidi;
        this.mercredisoir = mercredisoir;
        this.jeudimatin = jeudimatin;
        this.jeudiapmidi = jeudiapmidi;
        this.jeudisoir = jeudisoir;
        this.vendredimatin = vendredimatin;
        this.vendrediapmidi = vendrediapmidi;
        this.vendredisoir = vendredisoir;
        this.weekendmatin = weekendmatin;
        this.weekendapmidi = weekendapmidi;
        this.weekendsoir = weekendsoir;
       // this.tstBool = test;
    }

    public CalendrierDisponibilite() {
    }


    public boolean isPositive(int val){
        if(val == 1){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
/*
    @Bindable
    public int getTstBool() {
        return tstBool;
    }

    public void setTstBool(int tstBool) {
        this.tstBool = tstBool;
    }
*/

    @Bindable
    public int getDateModification() {
        return dateModification;
    }

    public void setDateModification(int dateModification) {
        this.dateModification = dateModification;
    }
    @Bindable
    public int getIdcalendrier() {
        return idcalendrier;
    }

    public void setIdcalendrier(int idcalendrier) {
        this.idcalendrier = idcalendrier;
    }
    @Bindable
    public int getIduser() {
        return iduser;
    }

    public void setIduser(int iduser) {
        this.iduser = iduser;
    }

    @Bindable
    public int getLundimatin() {
        return lundimatin;
    }

    public void setLundimatin(int lundimatin) {
        this.lundimatin = lundimatin;
    }
    @Bindable
    public int getLundiapmidi() {
        return lundiapmidi;
    }

    public void setLundiapmidi(int lundiapmidi) {
        this.lundiapmidi = lundiapmidi;
    }
    @Bindable
    public int getLundisoir() {
        return lundisoir;
    }

    public void setLundisoir(int lundisoir) {
        this.lundisoir = lundisoir;
    }
    @Bindable
    public int getMardimatin() {
        return mardimatin;
    }

    public void setMardimatin(int mardimatin) {
        this.mardimatin = mardimatin;
    }
    @Bindable
    public int getMardiapmidi() {
        return mardiapmidi;
    }

    public void setMardiapmidi(int mardiapmidi) {
        this.mardiapmidi = mardiapmidi;
    }
    @Bindable
    public int getMardisoir() {
        return mardisoir;
    }

    public void setMardisoir(int mardisoir) {
        this.mardisoir = mardisoir;
    }
    @Bindable
    public int getMercredimatin() {
        return mercredimatin;
    }

    public void setMercredimatin(int mercredimatin) {
        this.mercredimatin = mercredimatin;
    }
    @Bindable
    public int getMercrediapmidi() {
        return mercrediapmidi;
    }

    public void setMercrediapmidi(int mercrediapmidi) {
        this.mercrediapmidi = mercrediapmidi;
    }
    @Bindable
    public int getMercredisoir() {
        return mercredisoir;
    }

    public void setMercredisoir(int mercredisoir) {
        this.mercredisoir = mercredisoir;
    }
    @Bindable
    public int getJeudimatin() {
        return jeudimatin;
    }

    public void setJeudimatin(int jeudimatin) {
        this.jeudimatin = jeudimatin;
    }
    @Bindable
    public int getJeudiapmidi() {
        return jeudiapmidi;
    }

    public void setJeudiapmidi(int jeudiapmidi) {
        this.jeudiapmidi = jeudiapmidi;
    }
    @Bindable
    public int getJeudisoir() {
        return jeudisoir;
    }

    public void setJeudisoir(int jeudisoir) {
        this.jeudisoir = jeudisoir;
    }
    @Bindable
    public int getVendredimatin() {
        return vendredimatin;
    }

    public void setVendredimatin(int vendredimatin) {
        this.vendredimatin = vendredimatin;
    }
    @Bindable
    public int getVendrediapmidi() {
        return vendrediapmidi;
    }

    public void setVendrediapmidi(int vendrediapmidi) {
        this.vendrediapmidi = vendrediapmidi;
    }
    @Bindable
    public int getVendredisoir() {
        return vendredisoir;
    }

    public void setVendredisoir(int vendredisoir) {
        this.vendredisoir = vendredisoir;
    }
    @Bindable
    public int getWeekendmatin() {
        return weekendmatin;
    }

    public void setWeekendmatin(int weekendmatin) {
        this.weekendmatin = weekendmatin;
    }
    @Bindable
    public int getWeekendapmidi() {
        return weekendapmidi;
    }

    public void setWeekendapmidi(int weekendapmidi) {
        this.weekendapmidi = weekendapmidi;
    }
    @Bindable
    public int getWeekendsoir() {
        return weekendsoir;
    }

    public void setWeekendsoir(int weekendsoir) {
        this.weekendsoir = weekendsoir;
    }

    public CalendrierDisponibilite(Parcel in ) {
        this.idcalendrier = in.readInt();
        this.iduser = in.readInt();
        this.lundimatin = in.readInt();
        this.lundiapmidi = in.readInt();
        this.lundisoir = in.readInt();
        this.mardimatin = in.readInt();
        this.mardiapmidi = in.readInt();
        this.mardisoir = in.readInt();
        this.mercredimatin = in.readInt();
        this.mercrediapmidi = in.readInt();
        this.mercredisoir = in.readInt();
        this.jeudimatin = in.readInt();
        this.jeudiapmidi = in.readInt();
        this.jeudisoir = in.readInt();
        this.vendredimatin = in.readInt();
        this.vendrediapmidi = in.readInt();
        this.vendredisoir = in.readInt();
        this.weekendmatin = in.readInt();
        this.weekendapmidi = in.readInt();
        this.weekendsoir = in.readInt();
       // this.tstBool = in.readInt();
    }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(idcalendrier);
        dest.writeInt(iduser);
        dest.writeInt(lundimatin);
        dest.writeInt(lundiapmidi);
        dest.writeInt(lundisoir);
        dest.writeInt(mardimatin);
        dest.writeInt(mardiapmidi);
        dest.writeInt(mardisoir);
        dest.writeInt(mercredimatin);
        dest.writeInt(mercrediapmidi);
        dest.writeInt(mercredisoir);
        dest.writeInt(jeudimatin);
        dest.writeInt(jeudiapmidi);
        dest.writeInt(jeudisoir);
        dest.writeInt(vendredimatin);
        dest.writeInt(vendrediapmidi);
        dest.writeInt(vendredisoir);
        dest.writeInt(weekendmatin);
        dest.writeInt(weekendapmidi);
        dest.writeInt(weekendsoir);
    //    dest.writeInt(tstBool);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<CalendrierDisponibilite> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<CalendrierDisponibilite>() {

        public CalendrierDisponibilite createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new CalendrierDisponibilite(in);
        }

        public CalendrierDisponibilite[] newArray(int size) {
            return new CalendrierDisponibilite[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof CalendrierDisponibilite) {
            CalendrierDisponibilite toCompare = (CalendrierDisponibilite) obj;
            return (this.idcalendrier == toCompare.getIdcalendrier());
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (this.getIdcalendrier());
    }

}
```

and here is where I need it :

```
public RepoCalendrierDisponibilite(int idPersonne) throws IOException {
        this.calendrier = CallBy(idPersonne);
        this.idPersonne = idPersonne;

        Log.d("Calendrier Dispo : ", String.valueOf(this.calendrier.getDateModification()));
    }
```

and finally this is what I am getting using my controller (result seen in the browser):

```
{"idcalendrier":3,"iduser":3,"lundimatin":1,"lundiapmidi":1,"lundisoir":1,"mardimatin":1,"mardiapmidi":1,"mardisoir":1,"mercredimatin":1,"mercrediapmidi":1,"mercredisoir":1,"jeudimatin":1,"jeudiapmidi":1,"jeudisoir":1,"vendredimatin":1,"vendrediapmidi":1,"vendredisoir":1,"weekendmatin":1,"weekendapmidi":1,"weekendsoir":1,"DateModification":"2018-06-18T00:00:00"}
```

So it seems that my controller and data works.

my app has a problem in the execute() function. And as i have put a debbuger point that show nothing (the app just stops). I though it is maybe a problem of parsing ... but I lack experience with retrofit to identify if its that or something else.

Comment: Can you post the crash info from logcat here?

Comment: 07-02 06:38:57.268 4636-4663/com.example.dupla.sparktennis E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da

Comment: Well it doesn't reveal much to me. I don't know where to use this (note that I copied and past the only line that was colored in red).

Comment: Please use [`Call#enqueue(Callback)`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#enqueue-retrofit2.Callback-) to fire an asynchronous request to the server. The [Callback's](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Callback.html#onFailure-retrofit2.Call-java.lang.Throwable-) anonymous class implementation method [onFailure()](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Callback.html#onFailure-retrofit2.Call-java.lang.Throwable-) will give a `throwable`, you can check the error cause here.

Comment: No, I have already done it. (I wrote that in the description of my problem). and it just skip the onFailure methode therfore no throwable error message I could read in log. that's why i am pretty lost here. Moreover I call the method callBy , in a separated thread so by the end it will be asynchronous. But here is something I really don't know why it stops. I think about a problem during deserialisation. Well I don't know.

Comment: ok I haven't solved it yet, but it s pretty late here :) thank you for your help I'll continu tomorrow and post news if I have. Thank you "when the morning comes"

Comment: Ok, I've founded the solution : it was a parsing problem with my date. Probleme of deserialisation. That's all. thanks